# How to maximize sum of pairwise multiplication of array elements taken one from each array?

Tags: number-theory, optimization, permutations

Suppose you are given two arrays:

$$a = [a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n],\hspace{5mm} b = [b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots,b_n]$$

Now you need to take one element from $a$ and one from $b$ multiply it, and add to sum and remove those element. Do the same for all.

Now I want to maximize that sum ? How to go for this ?

Just To clear , take example :

$$a=[1,2],\hspace{5mm} b=[3,4]$$

$$\text{sum}_1 = 1\times3 +2\times4 = 11,\hspace{5mm}\text{sum}_2 = 1\times4 +2\times3 = 10$$

$$\text{sum} = \max\{\text{sum}_1,\text{sum}_2\} = 11$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p<q$ and $r<s$, we have $(pr+qs)-(ps+qr)=(q-p)(s-r)>0$.

This shows that if you have paired two $a$ values with two $b$ values, you are better off pairing the greater $a$ value with the greater $b$ value.  For any two pairs that this doesn't occur you should switch the pairings.  Eventually you will get the greatest $a$ value paired with the greatest $b$ value; and second highest values paired, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

By the [rearrangement inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), we can maximizing the sum by ordering both lists $a$ and $b$ from least element to greatest element and then taking the dot product.

In other words, rearrange $a$ such that $a_i<a_j$ whenever $i<j$, and rearrange $b$ similarly, and finally compute the sum
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_ib_i$$